# How to store the console output of a python file to a text file in idle ide

Tags: python, nltk, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I am new to python i am trying a opinion mining using twitter api and i have a large console output which i want to store in a text file. I am using IDLE ide for python and  my code is

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self,data):

    print (data)
    return True
def on_error(self,status):
    print (status)

if __name__=='__main__':

#This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, l)

#This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
stream.filter(track=['python', 'javascript', 'ruby'])
```

I am using

```
  python twitter_streaming.py > twitter_data.txt
```

but i am getting

```
>>> python twitter_streaming.py > twitter_data.txt
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to solve this , please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to do that from your console/cmd/powershell, not from within python!

Comment: @Zeokav  >>> python twitter_streaming.py > twitter_data.txt
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python twitter_streaming.py > twitter_data.txt
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Noo @Mandrek! That is telling your interpreter that python twitter_streaming.py > twitter_data.txt is a python statement (hence the error), when in fact it isn't.

Comment: @Zeokav then please tell me how i solve it . i am ver new to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question `**>>>** python twitter_streaming.py > twitter_data.txt` shows that you are running the command in Python interpreter's REPL. You have already invoked python and running it in interpreter mode.

As @Zeokav mentioned open terminal in Linux/Mac or cmd prompt in windows and then do `python twitter_streaming.py > twitter_data.txt`

Another issue with your code is indentations. I hope it is a formatting error if not the code should be like:

```
class className:
      def member_function(self):
          ...........
```

Comment: C:\Users\Jeet Chatterjee\NLP>python twitter_streaming.py > twitter_data.txt
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: nw i am doing this but no result

Comment: @Mandrek if you are using windows you should set  environment variable for python and the cmd will recognize the python

Comment: @gout i am doing this and its working C:\Users\Jeet Chatterjee\NLP>twitter_streaming.py > twitter_data.txt

Comment: Do you have  #!  as the first line of your python script .?  Only, in that case, a script file can be executed like a binary.

Comment: @gout, not on Windows. There are different ways to tell the DOS prompt that `.py` files should be run by the Python executable, and they don't involve putting anything in the script.

Comment: ASSOC and Ftype had to be modified to support that.